# Get hidden field value Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="conf1" value="7th IEEE/IFIP International Conference on Embedded and Ubiquitous Computing (EUC-09)">
    <input type="hidden" name="conf2" value="IEEE International Symposium on Parallel and Distributed Processsing with Applications">
    <input type="hidden" name="conf3" value="jkhga">
    <input type="hidden" name="conf4" value="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="conf5" value="The 3rd International Conference on Adaptive Business Information Systems (ABIS'09)">

    <input type="text" name="published">
```

And i am trying to get the values of the hidden fields in to an array using jquery. Here is what i have tried:

```
 var conferences = new Array();

        conferences[0] = $('#conf1').val();
        conferences[1] =$("[name='conf2']").val();
        conferences[2] =$("[name='conf3']").val();
        conferences[3] = $("[name='conf4']").val();
        conferences[4] =$("[name='conf5']").val();
```

Can anyone direct me on how to read them?
Thanks in Advance
Dean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're going to use jQuery, you can do this:

```
var array = $('input:hidden').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

`.map()` iterates over the collection, and places the return value into a jQuery object.

`.get()` retrieves the array from the jQuery object.

- http://api.jquery.com/map/
- http://api.jquery.com/get/

Answer (score 3):

```
var conferences = [];

$('input:hidden[name^="conf"]').each(function() {
    conferences.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var array = $.map($('input:hidden'),function(i) {
    return i.value;
});
```

This will assign an array of the values to `array` and is slightly less verbose than using `$(selector).map()` which returns a jQuery object that you then need to call `get()` on to return an array.

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2pH9m/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
var conferences = new Array();    // object Array

var conferencesVal = new Array(); // string Array

$("[type=hidden]").each(function(i,e){

   // object array  =>altarnatif method
   conferences.push( {name:$(this).attr("id"),value: $(this).val()});

   //string array
   conferencesVal[i]=  $(this).val();

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$(...).attr('value');
```

`.attr(...)` : is only getting the objects value at the start (when the html is created).
`.val()` : is getting the object's property value which can change many times.

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to explain whay `.val()` didn't work whereas `.attr()` works, so that people can better understand the problem and when this solution is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

[It looks to me like your code works fine already](http://jsbin.com/avabi3), except that there is no `#conf1`. Everything seems written correctly to the array, and can easily be accessed via `conferences[0]`, `conferences[1],` etc.

You could probably clean it up with jQuery tricks, but what you have is functional, if you know that you will only have 5 conferences.